# Node.js asynchronous coding difficulty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm trying to get multiple documents from MongoDB and send all the data in an array, but I'm having serious trouble understanding how this can be done with the event-driven Node.js.

The problem is that at the time `dataArray.push(tempObject)` is being executed, the `tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray` still has not been performed.

My code looks like this:

```
app.post('/api/charts', function(req, res) {
  var names = req.body.names;
  var categories = req.body.categories;

  var dataArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var tempObject = {};
    tempObject["name"] = names[i];
    Company.find({ name : names[i] }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      var tempDataArray = [];

      for (k = 0; k < categories.length; k++) {
        var tempDataObject = {};
        tempDataObject["name"] = categories[k];
        tempDataObject["numbers"] = result[0]["data"][categories[k]]["numbers"];
        tempDataObject["dates"] = result[0]["data"][categories[k]]["dates"];

        tempDataArray.push(tempDataObject);

      }
      tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray;
    });

    dataArray.push(tempObject);
  }

  res.send(dataArray);
});
```

Any suggestions on how to properly achieve the desired result would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use Promise objects in Nodejs?

Comment: I had similar difficulties understanding how this works. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852043/mongoose-find). In short you need to post process everything when you have your data - i.e. in your callback at find, both packaging and sending a response, as @kyrylkov said.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

```
https://github.com/caolan/async
```

And Using this code, your code will look like this:

```
var async = require("async");
app.post('/api/charts', function(req, res) {
    var names = req.body.names;
    var categories = req.body.categories;

    var dataArray = [];

    async.forEach(names, function(name, callback){

        var tempObject = {};
        tempObject["name"] = name;
        Company.find({ name : name }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                var tempDataArray = [];

                for (k = 0; k < categories.length; k++) {
                    var tempDataObject = {};
                    tempDataObject["name"] = categories[k];
                    tempDataObject["numbers"] = result[0]["data"][categories[k]]["numbers"];
                    tempDataObject["dates"] = result[0]["data"][categories[k]]["dates"];

                    tempDataArray.push(tempDataObject);

                }
                tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray;
                dataArray.push(tempObject);
                callback();
            }
        });
    }, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(dataArray);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes. In this forEach case, all names will be executed parallel and once all done, then you get last callback function(err) in which we have responded with res.send. In case you do not want to execute parallel or you want to maintain result order based on name array , then you can use forEachLimit

Answer (score 0):

The `Company.find()` method takes a callback function as it's second parameter. This callback is to be called after the company data is retrieved from the database. This means it could be anywhere between a few milliseconds and a few hundered milliseconds until it is called after calling the `Company.find()` method. But the code directly after `Company.find()` will not be delayed; it will be called straight away. So the callback delay is why `dataArray.push(tempObject)` is always called before `tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray`.

On top of this the outer for loop will run synchronously and on each iteration a separate DB call will be made. This isn't ideal so we want to get this for loop into the callback. So we can do something like:

```
app.post('/api/charts', function(req, res) {
    var names = req.body.names;
    var categories = req.body.categories;

    // we just do one DB query where all the data we need is returned
    Company.find({ name : names }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var dataArray = [];

        // we iteratre through each result in the callback, not outside it since
        // that would cause blocking due to synchronous operation
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var tempObject = {};
            tempObject["name"] = result[i].name;

            var tempDataArray = [];

            for (k = 0; k < categories.length; k++) {
                var tempDataObject = {};
                tempDataObject["name"] = categories[k];
                tempDataObject["numbers"] = result[i]["data"][categories[k]]["numbers"];
                tempDataObject["dates"] = result[i]["data"][categories[k]]["dates"];

                tempDataArray.push(tempDataObject);     
            }

            tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray;
            dataArray.push(tempObject);
        }
        res.send(dataArray);
    });
});
```

There are many approaches to abstract Nodes event driven nature such as Promises (which can be accessed either in ECMA Script 6 or a Promise library such as Bluebird, Async, etc.). But the above is a basic callback approach that is typically used in the likes of Express applications.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this :

```
tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray;
});
dataArray.push(tempObject);
```

To:

```
tempObject["data"] = tempDataArray;
dataArray.push(tempObject);
});
```

Comment: This is just going to push the problem out. `res.send(dataArray)` would be called before most, if not all, of the callbacks are executed. And it doesn't address the synchronous approach that is being used.