# getting undefined variable in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node to run this code

but when I run this code  get the undefined return from leadid variable in get function :

```
call = {};
call.hangup = {
    get: function(isOpen, ami, elastic, validator, growly, mysql, request){
        var self = call.hangup;
        this.isOpen = isOpen;
        this.ami = ami;
        this.elastic = elastic;
        this.validator = validator;
        this.growly = growly;
        this.mysql = mysql;
        this.request = request;
        if(isOpen)
        {
            ami.on('hangup', function(evt){
                var cause_status = parseInt(evt.cause);
                var message = self.causeStatus(cause_status);
                var channel = evt.channel;
                var isDAHDI = validator.contains(channel,"DAHDI");
                if((isDAHDI)&&(cause_status == 16)) 
                {

                    var mobile = evt.calleridnum;
                    if(validator.isLength(mobile,11))
                    {
                        if(validator.matches(mobile,/^09/i))
                        {   
                            var txtMessage = "";
                            var sending = "";
                            var leadid = self.searching(mobile, mysql, validator);

                           retrun leadid; ///  get the undefined !!!!


                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }else {
            console.log("Hangup's Event is OFF !");
        }       
    },
searching: function(number, mysql, validator){
    this.number = number;
    this.mysql = mysql;
    this.validator = validator;
    var query = "{sql ...}";

    mysql.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {        
    if (err) throw err; 
        if(!validator.isNull(rows))
        {               

            return rows[0].leadid;
        }else {
            return false;

        }
    });
},
};
module.exports = call;
```

this is how I call it in main file:

```
var call = require('./call');
    call.hangup.get(true, ami, client, validator, growly, connection, request);
```

in other hands when I call this function (searching) in the main file

```
new call.hangup.searching(number, connection, validator);
```

it's work correctly

how can I fix it ?

Comment: Why do you do `new self.searching` if `searching` is a method of the `call.hangup`? You are missed something in your studying...

Comment: @MysterX changed it, but error was the same :/

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem/understand why it did return `undefined`?

Comment: @pio what is your mean ?

Comment: I was trying to suggest that if my answer helped you in solving your problem please accept the answer. If you did not manage to solve the issue please follow up with your progress/where are you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that JavaScript is asynchronous.

When `searching` is called the database query is issued asynchronously and the function returns before the database would give you a result. In other words your `searching` function does not give you the result from

```
function(err, rows, fields) {        
if (err) throw err; 
    if(!validator.isNull(rows))
    {               

        return rows[0].leadid;
    }else {
        return false;

    }
}
```

as you would desire,

```
   searching: function(number, mysql, validator){
    this.number = number;
    this.mysql = mysql;
    this.validator = validator;
    var query = "{sql ...}";

    mysql.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {        
    if (err) throw err; 
        if(!validator.isNull(rows))
        {               

            return rows[0].leadid;
        }else {
            return false;

        }
    });
     --- > This is reached at the end of the call and nothing is returned },
    };
```

it does not return explicitly anything, hence the `undefined`.

You should either use [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or pass in `searching` a callback function that will be called when your database query returns.

So your solution should look like this:

```
get: function (...){
  ...
  self.searching(mobile, mysql, validator, whatIwantToDoAfterValidation)
},
searching: function(number, mysql, validator, callback){
   ...
   mysql.query(..., callback){
    if(!validator.isNull(rows))
    {               
        callback(rows[0].leadid);
    }else {
        callback(false);
    } 
   }
},
whatIwantToDoAfterValidation: function(leadid){
  ...do whatever you want with leadid...
}
```

Take a look at [`jquery's promises`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) to do the same thing with promises.

Comment: can you give me some example or resources ?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852043/mongoose-find) a while ago. You can find detailed explanations like [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) or google/search on stackoverlow "javascript callbacks".

Comment: The mozilla docs may not be the best thing to start with though.

Comment: How can I handle this example with your answer ?

Comment: can you explain mare about ? _pass in searching a callback function that will be called when your database query returns._

Comment: I think it is best if you postpone your development with a few hours and get to the bottom of understanding how asynchronous functions work. There are plenty of resources, e.g. [this](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks).

In short what I meant with the above phrase is: you don't know when `query` in `searching` finds the db record that your validation needs. But you want to do some action when it does so you need to pass in a function to be called when that happens. Asynchronous languages can be a bit tricky to understand at first.