# MongoDB won't return correct data first time round

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my code:

```
// Modules
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/affinity';
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
var user_data;

$(document).ready(function () {

   // Look through db for user
   // Flters through the db to find the user and their password to authenticate them in.
  userInfo = function (db, callback) {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var users = db.collection('users');

  // Searches through each user in the db to find one which meets conitions.
  var cursor = users.find({
     "username": username
  }, {"limit": 1} ).each(function (err, doc) {
     if (doc != null) {
        if (doc.password === password) {
           user_data = doc;
            //window.location.replace(__dirname + '/assets/views/main.html');
         } else {
            $("#error-hint").css(
               'visibility', 'visible'
            );
         }
      } else {
         // Skip user if it isn't matching
      }
   });
   console.log(user_data);
}

// Connects to database.
// Inserts all user data to the database.
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
   if (err) {
      console.log('Couldn\'t connect to the mongoDB server. \nERROR: ' + err);
   } else {
      var collection = db.collection('users');

      // When login button run authUser function
      $('#auth-btn').click(function () {
         userInfo(db, function () {
            db.close();
         });
      });
   }
});


 });
```

The problem is that when I click the button to auth the user in with correct info it returns a value of 'undefined' but without changing anything if I press the button a second time it returns the correct data from the database. I want it to display the first time round to properly authenticate the user in. What am I doing wrong ? please help.

Comment: did my answer help? If so please accept it, if no update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `console.log(user_data);` returns the `undefined` data?

That is because you are not calling it in the callback, so the first time the `console.log(user_data);` is called the db query did not find the user. When you call it the second time the first database query finished so `user_data` is already set so it will print it to you. Try looking up another user the second time you press the login button. It will print the first user's data.

Note that your calls are asynchronous! So in order to see the result of your query when it finishes just put the `console.log(user_data);` in the callback function passed into `each`.

Also if you want to limit your result set to only one element use `db.collection.fidnOne({...})` instead of `db.collection.find({...},{limit...}).each(...)`.

Comment: how would i export the results i get from the database so I can use it in another file.

Comment: Whatever you pass in to the callback of the `find` or `each` will be called on the data returned by the query. For a more complicated example see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852043/mongoose-find) .

Also note that your other file needs to be accessible in this context, so you most probably will need to include some parts of this file in your other file or the other file here.

If you're using express you already have a mechanism for this via the `module.exports` and `require`.

Comment: I get a undefined value back when calling it from another file.

Comment: Please update your question to correctly reflect the state of your code. Since the current question does not have any other file included and you haven't updated your code in the question I cannot tell what is wrong.